# Can javascript modify on-the-fly the contents of files uploaded as multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript

Scenario: a simple HTML form allows users to upload one or more files on their computer to a remote server (as multipart/form-data).

```
<form action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" multiple name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload">
<input type="submit" name="mybutton" id="mybutton" value="Upload" />
</form>  

<script> 
function latin2utf8(s){ return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)); }
</script>
```

Can javascript modify on the fly the contents of the files before they hit the wire? (ie. the remote server only sees the modified data)

I 'm trying to do (transparent) character encoding conversion of the uploaded text files (ie. Latin-X to Unicode UTF-8).  Is what I 'm after even possible? I' m basically looking for a javascript hook (callback?), that will let me apply latin2utf8() on the file contents before the browser POSTs them.

I have already tried [Mini Multiple File Upload](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) and [JQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/danielm/uploader/), but they don't seem to allow any  processing of the file contents.

Any javascript code doing something similar, or pointers to such would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Your question should show us that you did something. So the code you tried and the possible reasons it didn't work for you should be provided. Here is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Yes, the contents of the file can be modified before posting data. Can you include `html`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: Added simple HTML form and javascript code as per  guest271314 's suggestion.

Comment: Use (FileReader)[http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/] to read the contents of the file, modify it and then post it using an ajax request

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @dcohenb.  Unfortunately, assuming HTML5 support in all potential users' browser is just wishful thinking at this point.

Comment: what browser would your target users be using that isn't HTML5 compatible?  the only browsers that are on that list are ones that are base browsers bundled in deprecated versions of windows that aren't even supported anymore by the company that made them....

Comment: @Claies  Any browser, including "browsers bundled in deprecated versions of windows that aren't even supported anymore by the company that made them"  :-(

Comment: unless you *know for sure* that someone is using such an ancient browser, avoiding using current standards for such a low percentage (less than 1% worldwide) of "potential" users is probably more of a challenge than it's worth.  If avoiding HTML5 is a concern, you really should consider wording your question to make it clear that you need a legacy solution.

Comment: @Claies Having seen the User-Agent strings in the web server logs, I _know it for sure_.   (This is not a first world country...)